# JQuery restarts animation after stop() call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm a JQuery noob trying to make a horizontal scrolling `div`, which scrolls to the sides when the user hovers near the edges (specifically the leftmost or rightmost 10%).  When the mouse leaves the `div`, though, I want it to stop animating entirely.  The problem I'm experiencing is that it DOES stop, but then it immediately restarts again.

[Here's a JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/8EU9t/) that illustrates my issue.  Moving your mouse to the left or right 10% of the div gets it scrolling (all good), and then moving it back to the middle 80% stops it (all good).  Moving the mouse out of the div displays "EXITED" so we know it registered the `mouseleave` function (all good), and the animation promptly stops if it was going (all good).

BUT, the animation immediately restarts again!  And I have no idea why.  It obviously isn't calling the animate functions again because the "EXITED" is still displayed at the bottom, but I don't know how else it could start animating again.

Does anyone know why this is happening?  And more importantly, **does anyone know how to make the animations stop permanently** after `mouseleave`?

And for **bonus points:** is there a way to tell the animation "slow to a stop" instead of just stopping immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's happening because you're calling `.clearQueue()` after `.stop()` instead of before, if you change it to be the other way around it seems to work:

```
$(this).clearQueue().stop();
```

**[See this working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/Y3Xm4/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, this problem is solved by putting the stop function inside of the main function as such:

```
$(".scroller").mousemove(function(e){
var h = $('#innerscroller').width()+1130;
var offset = $($(this)).offset();
var position = (e.pageX-offset.left)/$(this).width();

if(position < 0.10) {
    $(this).animate({ scrollLeft: 0 }, 5000);
    $(".status").html(' Percentage:' + position.toFixed(2) + ' lefting');
} else if(position > 0.90) {
    $(this).animate({ scrollLeft: h }, 5000);
    $(".status").html(' Percentage:' + position.toFixed(2) + ' righting');
} else {
    $(this).stop().clearQueue();
    $(".status").html(' Percentage:' + position.toFixed(2));
}
$(".scroller").mouseleave(function(e){
$(this).stop().clearQueue();
$(".status").html('EXITED');
```

});
});

Here is the [modified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8EU9t/1/)

The .stop() function will only go to an abrupt stop so if you really want the slow to a stop I would use a technique like found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982630/how-to-slow-down-and-stop-current-jquery-animation)